# cannot access ImageInputStream

Tags: java, android

When I try to build my android project I am facing below error.

```
error: cannot access ImageInputStream class file for javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream not found
```

I could not find out the root cause. Can anyone please help to find out the issue.

Comment: Where did you find this class in the Android documentation? Why do you think it should be there?

Comment: show us some code.

Comment: check the error log for the reason of this problem, like the code which it comes from

Answer (score -1):

javax.imageio.stream package does not have a class named ImageInputStream. ImageInputStream is an interface which is implemented in a class called ImageInputStreamImpl. Use this class instead.

Comment: Why? Where does it say a class was expected? If the object implements  the interface, the interface is sufficient to access it.

Comment: True. However the error posted was 'cannot access ImageInputStream class file' , which leads me to believe that the person who posted the question required a class which implements the interface of the same name. Hence my answer.

Comment: But your answer doesn't make sense, wouldn't solve the problem, and 'class file' isn't the same thing as 'class'.